# What is wrong with matrix [[1,.5,0] [0,0,0] [0,.5,1]] steady state?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

I know that Markov matrices have steady state since they always have eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$. We just solve the system of equations $A\vec x = 1 \cdot \vec x$ or

$$\begin{cases}
k_{a\to a} a + k_{b\to a} b = a \\
k_{a\to b} a + k_{b\to b} b = b 
\end{cases}
$$

For instance, 
I see that $\begin{bmatrix}.9 & .5\\ .1 & .5 \end{bmatrix}$ expands to $
\begin{cases}
.9 a + .5 b = a \\
.1 a + .5 b = b 
\end{cases}
$ and both equations, in chorus, say that $b = a/5$.

This howerver can be derived more easily if we notice that dynamic balance is achieved when current from from $a \to b$ with coefficient .1 equals the current $b \to a$ with coeff .5. In this case we exploit only two coefficients: $.1a = .5b$, which immediately gives $b = .2a$ and proper feedback coefficients .9, .5 are ignored.

None of the approaches can be applied to

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & .5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & .5 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

however. Brute force gives

$\begin{cases}a & + .5b & &=& a \\ & 0 & &=& b \\ &.5 b& + c &=& c \end{cases}$

It says that $b = 0$ and nothing more. I do not see how another approach, with dynamic current equilibrium could be used here. I have got this matrix [analyzing the black-body isolation tents](http://valjok.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-much-light-does-pass-through.html). The 2x2 case is identity matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

, which does not shed light either. It says that if I had $[a_0, b_0]$ in the beginning, I will have that much in the end. In 3D case, initial condition $[a_0 b_0 c_0] = [0 1 0]$ must be ultimately transformed into $[a_0 + b_0/2,0,c_0 + b_0/2] = [b_0/2,0,b_0/2]$ but I do not see how does it happen.

Answer (score 1):

In general the steady state is not unique. In your case this is to be expected because your system will stay in state $1$ whenever it begins there and will stay in state $3$ whenever it begins there. As a result, all probability in state $2$ is divided (in this case evenly) between states $1$ and $3$ in the steady state. Hence you get a two parameter family of steady states, which is what was suggested from your linear system (any distribution which assigns no probability to state $2$ is a steady state of your system). Normalization reduces that to a one parameter family of steady states.

Comment: But I expected that steady state will somehow depend on the initial state. For instance, in my .9-0.1-0.5-0.5 matrix with steady state a = 5b means that initial mass $a_0 + b_0$, through $a+b=a_0+b_0$, will split into ${a_0 + b_0\over 6} \begin{bmatrix}5 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. I do not see how can I compute the same for my [[1,.5,0] [0,0,0] [0,.5,1]] matrix.

Comment: @RecognizeEvilasWaste In this special case you can pretty much just look at it: given an initial state $\begin{bmatrix} p_1 \\ p_2 \\ p_3 \end{bmatrix}$, it is changed to $\begin{bmatrix} p_1+p_2/2 \\ 0 \\ p_3+p_2/2 \end{bmatrix}$ which is a steady state already. In the general situation you need to diagonalize and then multiply the diagonalized form of the matrix with your initial condition, and take the limit (which will eliminate the contributions from any non-steady-state eigenvectors).

Comment: Yes, but I am unhappy because I cannot derive this latter vector from $A\vec x = \vec x.$

Comment: @RecognizeEvilasWaste In a certain limited sense you can. Whatever the steady state is, it is one of the normalized solutions to $Ax=x$. But there are more than one of those: in this case, there are two independent eigenvectors with eigenvalue 1, which means that there is a one parameter family of invariant distributions. Thus the steady state depends on the initial condition.

Comment: @RecognizeEvilasWaste In this case the invariant distributions are the vectors $\begin{bmatrix} p \\ 0 \\ 1-p \end{bmatrix}$ for each $p \in [0,1]$. Then $p=q_1+q_2/2$, where $q$ is the initial state.